# Why is the "help" button next to the comment text box so long?

Tags: discussion, comments

[image]

As you can see, when the help button is clicked, it shows the area the button occupies. Why is there lots of extra space on the right?

Comment: Why the downvote? I would be happy to know if there are any duplicates, or if you need more information

Comment: I'd guess folks are kinda confused as to what you hope to discuss here; there doesn't really seem to be a problem with the button, and if it's causing issues you didn't mention it - but it's not entirely clear if you're just asking out of curiosity either. Cardinal rule of stuff like this is to make your purpose clear; folks don't like to have to guess.

Answer (score 12):

The literal answer here is that the buttons are arranged using flex layout and so by default they're given the same width. Since the Add Comment button takes up that much room, so does the help button.

I suppose you might be curious why the designer here didn't go out of their way to make it smaller... Well, I guess that'd be more work for little if any benefit. If nothing else, easier to hit with fat fingers this way...

Comment: "*If nothing else, easier to hit with fat fingers this way...*" so, you are saying that fat fingered users need `help` hitting the button?